# ffmpeg conversion .dav to any video files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying for days to convert `.dav` file (file generated by dvrs [image recorders]). I have tried several variations with `ffmpeg` and can not succeed.

Command and console output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.dav -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -codec:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4 -movflags faststart -vf scale=-1:720,format=yuv420p output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, h264, from 'input.Dav':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 704x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Codec AVOption vbr (VBR mode (1-5)) specified for output file #0 (output.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] 264 - core 142 r2491 24e4fed - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1056x720, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   58 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      93kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=2124.9kbits/s    
frame=   76 fps= 71 q=28.0 size=     178kB time=00:00:01.08 bitrate=1347.6kbits/s    
frame=   94 fps= 58 q=28.0 size=     275kB time=00:00:01.80 bitrate=1251.3kbits/s    
frame=  106 fps= 50 q=28.0 size=     393kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=1412.9kbits/s    
frame=  122 fps= 46 q=28.0 size=     504kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate=1413.9kbits/s    
frame=  138 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=     586kB time=00:00:03.56 bitrate=1348.4kbits/s    
frame=  153 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=     676kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate=1330.4kbits/s    
[h264 @ 0x3348440] Frame num change from 35 to 162
[h264 @ 0x3348440] decode_slice_header error
frame=  166 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=     785kB time=00:00:04.68 bitrate=1374.8kbits/s    
frame=  179 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=     894kB time=00:00:05.20 bitrate=1407.9kbits/s    
frame=  191 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=    1010kB time=00:00:05.68 bitrate=1457.0kbits/s    
frame=  206 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=    1137kB time=00:00:06.28 bitrate=1482.7kbits/s    
frame=  222 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    1229kB time=00:00:06.92 bitrate=1455.2kbits/s    
frame=  239 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    1327kB time=00:00:07.60 bitrate=1430.8kbits/s    
frame=  258 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    1409kB time=00:00:08.36 bitrate=1380.4kbits/s    
frame=  273 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    1496kB time=00:00:08.96 bitrate=1367.5kbits/s    
frame=  288 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    1599kB time=00:00:09.56 bitrate=1370.3kbits/s    
frame=  301 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    1730kB time=00:00:10.08 bitrate=1405.7kbits/s    
frame=  318 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    1807kB time=00:00:10.76 bitrate=1376.0kbits/s    
frame=  336 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    1873kB time=00:00:11.48 bitrate=1336.3kbits/s    
frame=  358 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    1938kB time=00:00:12.36 bitrate=1284.4kbits/s    
frame=  378 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    1995kB time=00:00:13.16 bitrate=1242.1kbits/s    
frame=  398 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2053kB time=00:00:13.96 bitrate=1204.5kbits/s    
frame=  415 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2115kB time=00:00:14.64 bitrate=1183.4kbits/s    
frame=  434 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2165kB time=00:00:15.40 bitrate=1151.4kbits/s    
frame=  454 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2220kB time=00:00:16.20 bitrate=1122.8kbits/s    
frame=  470 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2279kB time=00:00:16.84 bitrate=1108.5kbits/s    
frame=  489 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2350kB time=00:00:17.60 bitrate=1093.9kbits/s    
frame=  505 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    2410kB time=00:00:18.24 bitrate=1082.5kbits/s    
frame=  515 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    2534kB time=00:00:18.64 bitrate=1113.5kbits/s    
frame=  531 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    2668kB time=00:00:19.28 bitrate=1133.8kbits/s    
frame=  547 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    2782kB time=00:00:19.92 bitrate=1144.2kbits/s    
frame=  565 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    2925kB time=00:00:20.64 bitrate=1160.9kbits/s    
frame=  581 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    3043kB time=00:00:21.28 bitrate=1171.3kbits/s    
frame=  595 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    3136kB time=00:00:21.84 bitrate=1176.1kbits/s    
frame=  611 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    3240kB time=00:00:22.48 bitrate=1180.5kbits/s    
frame=  630 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    3351kB time=00:00:23.24 bitrate=1181.2kbits/s    
frame=  651 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    3451kB time=00:00:24.08 bitrate=1174.1kbits/s    
frame=  675 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=    3528kB time=00:00:25.04 bitrate=1154.2kbits/s    
frame=  700 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    3612kB time=00:00:26.04 bitrate=1136.2kbits/s    
frame=  724 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    3701kB time=00:00:27.00 bitrate=1122.9kbits/s    
frame=  747 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    3808kB time=00:00:27.92 bitrate=1117.4kbits/s    
frame=  768 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=    3884kB time=00:00:28.76 bitrate=1106.4kbits/s    
frame=  799 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=    3983kB time=00:00:30.00 bitrate=1087.6kbits/s    
frame=  834 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=    4052kB time=00:00:31.40 bitrate=1057.1kbits/s    
frame=  868 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4097kB time=00:00:32.76 bitrate=1024.5kbits/s    
frame=  894 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4141kB time=00:00:33.80 bitrate=1003.6kbits/s    
frame=  914 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4234kB time=00:00:34.60 bitrate=1002.5kbits/s    
frame=  933 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4363kB time=00:00:35.36 bitrate=1010.8kbits/s    
frame=  954 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4442kB time=00:00:36.20 bitrate=1005.3kbits/s    
frame=  976 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4510kB time=00:00:37.08 bitrate= 996.3kbits/s    
frame=  994 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4579kB time=00:00:37.80 bitrate= 992.3kbits/s    
frame= 1010 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4663kB time=00:00:38.44 bitrate= 993.7kbits/s    
frame= 1030 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4734kB time=00:00:39.24 bitrate= 988.3kbits/s    
frame= 1043 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    4843kB time=00:00:39.76 bitrate= 997.9kbits/s    
frame= 1065 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    5021kB time=00:00:40.64 bitrate=1012.1kbits/s    
frame= 1092 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5052kB time=00:00:41.72 bitrate= 991.9kbits/s    
frame= 1118 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5129kB time=00:00:42.76 bitrate= 982.6kbits/s    
frame= 1145 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5185kB time=00:00:43.84 bitrate= 968.8kbits/s    
frame= 1174 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5214kB time=00:00:45.00 bitrate= 949.1kbits/s    
frame= 1202 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    5256kB time=00:00:46.12 bitrate= 933.7kbits/s    
frame= 1220 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    5341kB time=00:00:46.84 bitrate= 934.1kbits/s    
frame= 1236 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5432kB time=00:00:47.48 bitrate= 937.2kbits/s    
[h264 @ 0x2d68ca0] A non-intra slice in an IDR NAL unit.
[h264 @ 0x2d68ca0] decode_slice_header error
frame= 1252 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5552kB time=00:00:48.12 bitrate= 945.2kbits/s    
frame= 1269 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5666kB time=00:00:48.80 bitrate= 951.2kbits/s    
frame= 1286 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5773kB time=00:00:49.48 bitrate= 955.7kbits/s    
frame= 1302 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    5908kB time=00:00:50.12 bitrate= 965.7kbits/s    
frame= 1324 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    6011kB time=00:00:51.00 bitrate= 965.6kbits/s    
frame= 1349 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    6103kB time=00:00:52.00 bitrate= 961.4kbits/s    
frame= 1373 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=    6200kB time=00:00:52.96 bitrate= 959.1kbits/s    
frame= 1399 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6284kB time=00:00:54.00 bitrate= 953.3kbits/s    
frame= 1424 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6388kB time=00:00:55.00 bitrate= 951.5kbits/s    
frame= 1447 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6492kB time=00:00:55.92 bitrate= 951.1kbits/s    
frame= 1476 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6530kB time=00:00:57.08 bitrate= 937.2kbits/s    
frame= 1503 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6580kB time=00:00:58.16 bitrate= 926.8kbits/s    
frame= 1518 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6709kB time=00:00:58.76 bitrate= 935.4kbits/s    
frame= 1542 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6835kB time=00:00:59.72 bitrate= 937.6kbits/s    
[h264 @ 0x3348440] data partitioning is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[h264 @ 0x3348440] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)
frame= 1568 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    6958kB time=00:01:00.76 bitrate= 938.1kbits/s    
frame= 1596 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    7006kB time=00:01:01.88 bitrate= 927.5kbits/s    
frame= 1619 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=    7096kB time=00:01:02.80 bitrate= 925.6kbits/s    
frame= 1646 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7152kB time=00:01:03.88 bitrate= 917.2kbits/s    
frame= 1671 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7205kB time=00:01:04.88 bitrate= 909.8kbits/s    
frame= 1698 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7268kB time=00:01:05.96 bitrate= 902.7kbits/s    
frame= 1725 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7328kB time=00:01:07.04 bitrate= 895.5kbits/s    
frame= 1752 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7382kB time=00:01:08.12 bitrate= 887.7kbits/s    
frame= 1779 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7433kB time=00:01:09.20 bitrate= 879.9kbits/s    
frame= 1803 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=    7580kB time=00:01:10.16 bitrate= 885.1kbits/s    
frame= 1827 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    7643kB time=00:01:11.12 bitrate= 880.4kbits/s    
frame= 1852 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    7703kB time=00:01:12.12 bitrate= 875.0kbits/s    
frame= 1879 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    7751kB time=00:01:13.20 bitrate= 867.4kbits/s    
frame= 1899 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    7840kB time=00:01:14.00 bitrate= 867.9kbits/s    
frame= 1918 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    7946kB time=00:01:14.76 bitrate= 870.7kbits/s    
frame= 1938 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    8046kB time=00:01:15.56 bitrate= 872.3kbits/s    
frame= 1959 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    8134kB time=00:01:16.40 bitrate= 872.1kbits/s    
frame= 1978 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    8227kB time=00:01:17.16 bitrate= 873.5kbits/s    
frame= 1997 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    8322kB time=00:01:17.92 bitrate= 874.9kbits/s    
frame= 2022 fps= 41 q=28.0 size=    8390kB time=00:01:18.92 bitrate= 870.9kbits/s    
[h264 @ 0x2d64180] concealing 1320 DC, 1320 AC, 1320 MV errors in I frame
[mp4 @ 0x2cdb900] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame= 2041 fps= 40 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8657kB time=00:01:21.56 bitrate= 869.5kbits/s    
video:8633kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.275387%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] frame I:9     Avg QP:18.32  size: 48212
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] frame P:698   Avg QP:22.05  size:  9056
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] frame B:1334  Avg QP:27.18  size:  1562
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] consecutive B-frames: 10.6%  5.0%  5.4% 79.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] mb I  I16..4: 18.4% 57.3% 24.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] mb P  I16..4:  5.3%  8.2%  1.0%  P16..4: 26.3%  9.1%  4.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:46.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 20.6%  1.8%  0.3%  direct: 0.8%  skip:76.2%  L0:38.8% L1:57.6% BI: 3.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] 8x8 transform intra:56.1% inter:75.9%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 35.0% 44.9% 12.4% inter: 6.5% 8.1% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 34% 40%  3% 22%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 26% 16%  3%  4%  4%  5%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 41% 10%  2%  4%  4%  5%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 24% 24%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] ref P L0: 72.8% 10.0% 13.7%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] ref B L0: 90.8%  7.9%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] ref B L1: 96.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x2d99e00] kb/s:866.17
```

Comment: Shure, link .dav file: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/e7459942
I Use Intelbras Media Player for play.
No, video output don't have audio, and sometimes the image are grey collor.

Comment: This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077842/how-to-wait-for-file-close-in-linux

Comment: What is not working?  Your output here seems to imply it is creating a new file...

Answer (score 39):

Using ffmpeg from dav to mp4

```
ffmpeg -y -i input-file.dav -c:v libx264 -crf 24 output-file.mp4
```

I use for security cameras and add `-filter:v "setpts=3*PTS"` param to slow video.

[Reference to solution here](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-March/031177.html)

Comment: I'd love some expansion on what options you are using and why. I am reading the docs but certainly much easier for you to elaborate. :)

Comment: FFmpeg appears to work but in reality it encodes nothing.

Comment: stbnrivas - your command works perfectly! I know now why they use .dav. It has higher compressing rate than .mp4

Answer (score 8):

`ffmpeg` doesn't support `DAV` (yet) as shown by `ffmpeg -formats`.

The reason why it appears to work for a while is because `DAV` is a Chinese modified version of `H.264/AVC`. `ffmpeg` attempts to guess your input format and it settles on its standard `H.264` decoder as the best available match.

The decoding obviously fails at some point since `DAV` has vendor specific modifications. The format is also proprietary.

You can see this by running the following command:

`ffprobe -i input.dav -v debug`

The result is:

`[h264 @ 0x264ec00] Format h264 probed with size=2048 and score=51`

The score is only `51/100`.

Comment: hummmm, perfect answer. Thak you so much!!
Do you know how can i do it's conversion for command line?
I use one software, but he not accept command line...
If you can help with it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There seems to be some form of batch converter available over at http://www.bahamassecurity.com. Haven't tried it and I don't know who's behind the site so handle with care. All `dav` converter software looks kind of shady.

Comment: That's okay, i appreciate you help (:

Comment: Looks like time has caught up. I now see "Format dhav probed with size=2048 and score=100" on ffmpeg 4.2.1, which is pretty neat.

Comment: *The score is only 51/100* --> the H264 raw demuxer probe can only return 0 or 51, so it's best possible match :)

Answer (score 2):

```
REM Convert DAV to MP4 and Concatenate and merge Files 
c:\RecordDownload\bin\ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -y -f concat -i mylist.txt -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -filter:v "setpts=1*PTS" MERGED.mp4

REM Take merged video and speed it up for survey
c:\RecordDownload\bin\ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -i MERGED.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.1*PTS" FASTMERGED.mp4
```

This is what I used for a windows batch file that works, but I have found empirically that the amount of data generated by 6 3MP or 4MP cameras is overwhelming to process.  I don't know if this will help

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through above process and it was quite successful, only limit was in performing the operation with multiple files in batch.
So, I came up with following solution.

1. First install ffmpeg

`sudo apt  install ffmpeg`

2. Save following as *convert.py* then

```
import subprocess
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(".") if isfile(join(".", f))]

c=1
for i in onlyfiles:
    
    c=c+1
    list_dir = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-y","-i",i,"-c:v","libx264","-crf","24",i[:-4]+".mp4"])
    list_dir.wait()
```

3. Run the code
   `python convert.py`

Comment: It works fine! The code is missing the: import subprocess line

Comment: This answer completely overshoots the question. It doesn't ask for some batch processing method, it asks how to convert a .dav file to a .mp4 file using ffmpeg.
Sure, it's in there somewhere, but you overcomplicated it a lot.

Comment: Dear Nox, I believe you have not read the answer. That clearly states "I have gone through the above process and it was quite successful, the only limit was in performing the operation with multiple files in batch. So, I came up with the following solution." This conversion is used for multiple files. So it is obvious I am trying to tackle a general problem in this. PS kindly tell if you have any problem with grammar or language.

Answer (score 2):

@stbnrivas's command worked for me but it took several minutes to convert file which probably doesn't need video processing at all. This command converts DAV to AVI probably just setting correct header. So it runs instantly.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.dav -vcodec copy output.avi
```

Found [here](https://ipcamtalk.com/threads/recommend-dav-to-mp4-converter-please.30193/#post-349885).

Comment: `-movflags +faststart` is only for MP4 and related. It is ignored for AVI.

Comment: @llogan Thank you. You are right, it generates identical file without these options so I remove them.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%i in (*.dav) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c:v libx264 "%%~i.mp4"
)
done
```

Try this for batch conversation.
I have used another version of this to convert images & mp3's to videos.
You probably need to tweak it a liitle to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I spend few hours on unsuccessful attempts to do it with ffmpeg.

Problems: lower fps, processing stopping on with `no frame` error. Seems camera merges video stream in way that ffmpeg can't understand.

As I research, `.DAV` is kinda closed format from `Dahua` company.

`Smart Player` has ability to export video to AVI and it works for me. But it's Windows software.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up off of @Dron007's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69557270/1445674,
my DVR records in x265 so `.avi` extension didn't work for me, but `.mp4` did. I assume it's setting the correct headers as they mentioned.

`ffmpeg -y -i input.dav -vcodec copy output.mp4`