# how to convert multiple .dav files in a directory to .mp4

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, terminal, mp4, dav-file

I have a bunch of .dav files in a directory, need to convert all the files in the directory to .mp4 format. I'm on Linux btw, so looking for a commandline option preferably

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of digging, found the solution I was looking for. Bash is your friend :)

cd to the directory:

```
for i in `ll|awk '{print $9}'|cut -d '.' -f1`;do ffmpeg -y -i $i.dav -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -filter:v "setpts=1*PTS" $i.mp4; done
```

Reference to the ffmpeg solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827539/ffmpeg-conversion-dav-to-any-video-files)

Comment: No need for `-filter:v "setpts=1*PTS"`: it is doing nothing. [Avoid using `ls` to provide file names](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2045). You can just do this: `for i in *.dav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done` adapted from [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/1109017)

Comment: okay much better, thank you